# How to remove a random element after being printed

Tags: android, kotlin, random, mutablelist

```
fun main() {
    val oda1 = mutableListOf("kadir", "talha", "oğuz")
    println("first winner is ${oda1.random()}") 
}
```

I can print a random name with this method, but I want to continue to get a second random name too(rather than a selected one). My question is; How can I remove the printed string element, and get a random name with remained names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to save the current random name to remove it from the list after print it

```
fun main() {
    val oda1 = mutableListOf("kadir", "talha", "oğuz")
    val winner = oda1.random()
    println("first winner is $winner")
    oda1.remove(winner)
    println("Other winners $oda1")
}
```

output

first winner is kadir

Other winners [talha, oğuz]

Comment: fun main() {
    val oda1 = mutableListOf("kadir", "talha", "oğuz")
    val winner = oda1.random()
    println("first winner is $winner")
    oda1.remove(winner)
    println("second winner is ${oda1.random()}")
} 
I edited code a little, and it is working for me! than you!

Answer (score 0):

It's super simple.
First, you get the random element from the list
Then, you do something with it (for example printing the name)
Finally, you have to remove that name from the current list.

Something like this

```
val oda1 = mutableListOf("kadir", "talha", "oğuz")
  val randomElement = oda1.random()
  println("Random name is ${randomElement}")
  oda1.remove(randomElement)
```

Comment: the other answer was what I was looking for, but thank you for answering my question! :)